# how to uninstall mpich2 package from cygwin without setup

Tags: cygwin, mpich

I have installed on cygwin (w7) this old release of mpich2-1.2.1p1 installing it using configure, make, make install command, now I would like to uninstall it, I have looked into cygwin documentation, user guide, and the web, it seems that I have not find a good answer, can you suggest some way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall it, you need a list of created files. Perhaps you could install it again to a temp dir, in order to get the list of files that need to be removed.

```
make install DESTDIR=/tmp
find /tmp -type f
```

Comment: If he answered your question, you should mark it as answered so it won't show up in the unanswered queue anymore.